# Bitlocker wrote header to volume but didn't actually encrypt drive?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, encryption, bitlocker, filesystem-corruption

I was attempting to configure Bitlocker on my laptop which has two volumes: a boot SSD (C:) and a larger spinning disk (D:).  When I first tried to encrypt the entire C: (boot) drive, it told me that it couldn't do it at that time and required a reboot.  I saved the recovery key information to a secure location, and moved on to encrypting my spinning disk.  The encryption of that volume completed in about 16 hours with no errors.

I then rebooted the laptop to allow it to do the encryption of the boot volume.  I was greeted with the password prompt to decrypt the Bitlocker volume, and I entered the password I chose when setting up the encryption, but it immediately started booting into the recovery partition.  After trying to get the system to boot multiple times, I finally entered the command prompt in the recovery partition, and used `manage-bde` to try and decrypt the C: drive.

`manage-bde` reports that it is unable to decrypt the partition using both the password I created (and was accepted by the original Bitlocker boot screen), nor the recovery password (yes, I tried entering them multiple times, even using a copy-and-paste in the terminal window for the recovery password after copying the recovery file to a USB key and mounting it on the computer).  `manage-bde` has no issue with decrypting and mounting my spinning disk that encrypted without error.

Next, I booted up on System Rescue CD from a USB stick, and used `dd` piped to `hexdump -C` of the original NTFS partition to investigate what is going on.  Sure enough the partition header matches that of a 
[Bitlocker volume header](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/BitLocker_Disk_Encryption).  However, the contents at offset `00a0` do not match the "magic header" as described in the previous link (whereas it does on my correctly-encrypted volume).  As I delve even further into the volume, I can see plain-text contents of files and even what appear to be file entry headers with filenames!  I use the same process to explore the contents of the volume that was successfully encrypted, and I can't find any meaningful information as I page through the blocks of the device.

What can I do to restore the partition header so everything recognizes this partition as an NTFS volume?  `ntfs-3g` doesn't like the partition, and I'd rather get advice before attempting to manually edit the partition header on my own.

Thanks in advance for reading my long issue!

Comment: If someone ends up here as a result of a Google search, it is my sad duty to inform you that I was not able to solve this problem on my own.  I also posted on the Bitlocker forums on TechNet, and the only reply I received suggested running some commands that made zero changes to the system.  After a week without my laptop I finally gave up and had to reformat the volume and reinstall Windows.  Best of luck to you if you're in the same boat; sorry I don't have better news.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP ended up reformatting the system making further troubleshooting impossible.